# Jmeter : Application uses _session_id in cookie to maintain session. It is being maintained from login to logout. I need to correlate it

Tags: regex, jmeter, session-cookies, correlation

Jmeter : Application uses _session_id in cookie to maintain session.
It is visible in get request. It is being maintained from the time of login till logout. I need to correlate it to test the performance.

I have used regex extractor to extract the _session_id as below: 
In regular expression **_session_id=(\w+)** 

specified **template as $1$**

and in regex user parameters "tSess" I have specified as parameter name regex group number as 1 and parameter value regex group number as 1.

I have used HTTP cookie manager with _session_id name and value as tSess.

I ran the script but I found that _session_id is appended in post data and it is empty like "_session_id=", nothing after "=".

I was also using HTTP URL re-writing modifier so above was occuring but I have removed it and now there is no _session_id appended in post data.

How can I correlate.

Application is in ruby.

Comment: You should provide at least one example for the response that contains the cookie to be extracted, otherwise I don't see how anybody could help you. Also upload your JMeter profile somewhere, or provide a picture of the structure.  [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I cant post images as I dont have enough reputation points. :(. If that is the case then I will delete this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using HTTP Cookie Manager you don't need to correlate the cookie via Regular Expression Extractor.

If you need to get the cookie value for some reason - you can just add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

After JMeter restart you'll be able to access your cookies as usual JMeter variables prefixed with `COOKIE_` so if your cookie is `_session_id` you should be able to refer it as `${COOKIE__session_id}`

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) guide for more information on representing and dealing with cookies in Apache JMeter.